# Angular UI-Router - Resolve data in root state and use in $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI-Router to achieve state within my frontend app. I've got a `resolve` group on my abstract base state, which I extend from with all of my child states, but I'm experiencing issues:

I looked at this Q/A:
[How do I access the 'resolve' property of a UI-Router root state from $stateChangeStart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141736/how-do-i-access-the-resolve-property-of-a-ui-router-root-state-from-statechan)
... but it didn't really answer my question. Here's the code:

```
.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'build/views/layout/master.html',
    data: {
        doesRequireLogin: true
    },
    resolve: {
        principalRoles: function($q, User, RoleMapping, $rootScope) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Grab the current user, then attempt to find their roles
            User.getCurrent(
                function foundUser(user) {

                    RoleMapping.find({
                        filter: {
                            where: {
                                principalId: user.id
                            },
                            include: 'role'
                        }
                    }, function hasRoles(roleMappings) {

                        // Reduce the roles list to just the names of the roles
                        var rolesList = roleMappings.map(function(mapping) {
                            return mapping.role ? mapping.role.name : '';
                        });

                        $rootScope.user.roles = rolesList;

                        return deferred.resolve(rolesList);

                    }, function hasError(error) {
                        return deferred.reject(error);
                    });

                },
                function userError(error) {
                    return deferred.reject(error);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;

        }
    }
})
```

This works fine, seems to return the information I need. However my issue is that inside my `.run` block, I have the following code:

```
// Intercept state changes to see if we need to log in
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState,   toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) {

    console.log(arguments);

    var requireLogin = toState.data.doesRequireLogin;
    console.log(toState.data.principalRoles);

    try {
        // this only works because i assign this in the state, 
        // probably not the best idea, 
        // and besides it only works *after* the first page load, never initially
        console.log($rootScope.user.roles);
    }
    catch(e) {}

    if (requireLogin && !$rootScope.isAuthenticated) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('auth')
    }

});
```

This only works on subsequent state changes *after the initial page load*, can you think of how I could return the current user's roles for all instances?

Comment: *Just a note, this answer could show you, how to use service as a holder of the authentication information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310*

Comment: This looks to solve my issue, will report back when I've tried if :-)

Comment: This works, with a bit of fiddling - thank you Radim :)

Comment: Great to see that, sir. Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by following Radim's answer in the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26702638/1679310